# Can't solve HTTP error 429 with Sys.sleep()

Tags: r, web-scraping, http-status-code-429

**I tried this code but the server sends me back the HTTP 429 error for too many requests.The code runs if i make one single function for each car attribute but i want them separeted because in order to move further in my analysis i will run radnom forest and regression trees.Note that even with time sleep the code doesn't run.**

```r
library("robotstxt")
library("dplyr")
library("rvest")

###### Empty Data frame
CARS<-data.frame()

for (page_result in seq(from=1, to=2710)) {
  link<-paste0("https://www.car.gr/classifieds/cars/?fs=1&condition=used&offer_type=sale&significant_damage=f&modified=15&pg=",
               page_result)
  
  page<-curl::curl(link) %>% read_html(link)
  
  sleep_list<-c(8,10,7)                                                            ##########Delay the code 
  i<-sample(sleep_list,1)
  Sys.sleep(i)
  name<-read_html(link)
  Sys.sleep(i)
  Title<-page %>% html_nodes(".title") %>% html_text2()                                      #####Web scrap for the names
  Sys.sleep(i)
  Price<-page %>% html_nodes(".price-fmt") %>% html_text2()                                  #####Web scrap for the prices    
  Sys.sleep(i)
  car_links<-page %>% html_nodes(".row-anchor") %>% 
    html_attr("href") %>% paste0("https://www.car.gr", .)                                    #######extract the links of each car to scrap     
  Sys.sleep(i)
  color<-sapply(car_links,get_color,simplify = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(i)
  gearing_system<-sapply(car_links,get_gearing_sys)
  Sys.sleep(i)
  HP<-sapply(car_links,get_car_HP,simplify = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(i)
  CC<-sapply(car_links,get_car_CC,simplify = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(i)
  FUEL<-sapply(car_links,get_car_fuel,simplify = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(i)
  KM<-sapply(car_links,get_car_km,simplify = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(i)
  DATE<-sapply(car_links,get_car_km,simplify = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(i)
  CATEGORY<-sapply(car_links,get_car_category,simplify = TRUE) 
  Sys.sleep(i)
  SELLER<-SAPPLY(car_links,get_seller,simplify = TRUE)
  CARS <- rbind(CARS,data.frame(Title,Price,color,gearing_system,HP,CC,FUEL,KM,DATE,SELLER,stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  
  print(paste("Page", page_result,"of","2710"))
}

######## Functions for getting each single attributes in one single scrap

get_seller<- function(car_link){  
  car_page<-read_html(car_link)
  car_page<-read_html(link) %>% html_node(".tw-my-2:nth-child(11) .tw-text-xl") %>% html_text2()
  return(SELLER)
}

get_color<-function(car_link){
  car_page<-read_html(car_link)
  car_color<-car_page %>% html_node("tr:nth-child(12) span") %>% html_text2()
  return(car_color)
}

get_gearing_sys<-function(car_link){
  car_page<-read_html(car_link)
  car_gearing_sys<-car_page %>% html_node("tr:nth-child(11) span") %>% html_text2()
  return(car_gearing_sys)
}

get_car_HP<-function(car_link){
  car_page<-read_html(car_link)
  car_HP<-car_page %>% html_node("tr:nth-child(10) span") %>% html_text2()
  return(car_HP)
}

get_car_CC<- function(car_link){
  car_page<-read_html(car_link)
  car_CC<- car_page %>% html_node("tr:nth-child(9) span") %>% html_text2()
  return(car_CC)
}

get_car_fuel<- function(car_link){
  car_page<-read_html(car_link)
  car_fuel<-car_page %>% html_node("tr:nth-child(8) span") %>% html_text2()
  return(car_fuel)
}

get_car_km<- function(car_link){
  car_page<-read_html(car_link)
  car_km<- car_page %>% html_node("tr:nth-child(7) span") %>% html_text2()
  return(car_km)
}

get_car_date<-function(car_link){
  car_page<-read_html(car_link)
  car_date<- car_page %>% html_node("tr:nth-child(6) span") %>% html_text2()
  return(car_date)
}

get_car_category<- function(car_link){
  car_page<-read_html(car_link)
  car_category<-car_page %>% html_node(".tw-col-span-6:nth-child(6)") %>% html_text2()
  return(car_category)
}
```

Comment: Maybe you’ve annoyed the site admins so much they’ve blocked you…

Comment: yeah but they allow scraping,paths_allowed via robotstxt returns TRUE which means i can get info from there and including the timer everything should have been ok.

Comment: As I said in your previous question, I believe _presence_ in a `robots.txt` file does not by itself suggest queries-over-time. I really don't know that we (Stack community) can inform this question much unless we have experience with _that_ specific API (not just APIs in general). Have you reached out to the site admins? Often a well-placed question can inform you why things are stopping, and might even open some doors for you.